# Unwanted submodules pushing to GitHub

Tags: javascript, html, git, github, git-submodules

Every time I push a file to Github it uploads as a submodule! How do I keep this from happening? Is there a way to reverse the submodule and upload like the rest of the files inside of the folder?

Comment: please share more details, that would be helpful to solve your issue or find an idea

Comment: if you delete the .git folder in the submodule it will become part of the parent repo. YOU WILL LOSE ALL OF THE HISTORY OF THE SUBMODULE, so, if you're not sure, make a backup of it somewhere so you can restore it if you change your mind.

Comment: Note that Git pushes *commits*, not files: you make a commit (which holds a snapshot of *every* file) and push that. In the case of a submodule, the commit you're making holds a *gitlink*, which is a reference that says *in this submodule, use commit #12345* or whatever the number may be. The file itself is is in a commit in *some other repository entirely*. Clearly not what you want here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check first if you have multiple .git folder

- one for you main local repository
- one for some subfolders inside your local repository

That would means "nested Git repositories", which would be uploaded to GitHub as a "gitlink" (a reference to the root tree SHA1 of the nested repo)

Removing those nested `.git` subfolders (assuming you don't need the internal history) would allow to add, commit and push the actual content of those subfolders.

Comment: @ChazCarothers Great, well done!